# which gives performance in java ?storing value in variable then use it or direct use of value from single row.i am getting row from result set?

Tags: java, performance, jdbc

I am getting value from single row using `resultSet`. which is better:

- store that value in variable and multiple time use that variable in while loop?
- direct use of value without store it into variable ?

Comment: Don't spend time worrying about infinitesimal theoretical performance hacks. Write whatever is simplest and easiest to understand. The performance difference isn't significant, and the JIT might collapse it anyway.

Comment: what is efficient  ?option 1 or option 2? what most programmer prefer in this case?

Comment: Most programmers will extract the variable out of pure habit. Do not repeat method invocations, especially not in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a value from a `ResultSet` does not come for free, and if you have to use the value several times you should store it in a local variable instead of re-reading it each time.

Comment: in whlie loop , what is good direct use of fetched value or store that fetched value in variable then use it in while loop multiple time?this kind of things affect performance ?

Comment: @patel I'm not sure how the question in your comment differs from the original question?

Answer (score 0):

If you read a value multiple times from `ResultSet` it requires some overhead but since `ResultSet` uses client side cache the retrieval will be fast. But it is better/faster to store it in a variable and use it, if it is required to be used multiple times (the difference should be very very small). But as chrylis commented, you should not worry about such small performance hacks.